# PostgreSQL Full Text Search (FTS), what is the difference between ::tsvector and to_tsvector()?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, cast

i have a table with tsvector type column (**col**).

I fill some rows via script and use cast **data::tsvector**, but (!) some rows was filled with **to_tsvector(data)**, so i have rows with different values like this:

1. `'в' 'г' 'зея' 'иеговы' 'местная' 'организация' 'религиозная' 'свидетелей'`
2. `'г':7 'зе':8 'иегов':5 'местн':1 'организац':3 'религиозн':2 'свидетел':4`

It was surprise for me :) So what the overhead for values not prepaired with **to_tsvector(data)** ? Will pg do to_tsvector on runtime or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the `string->tsvector` cast and the function-constructor `to_tsvector(text)`

1. the cast (`::`) assumes the input is already a tsvector that's been casted to text. It **does not** use the language-specific stubbing mechanisms or store positional information, it simply assumes it is given a space-delimited text-search tokens (positions and lexemes) and assumes they've already undergone the proceess.
2. `to_tsvector()` takes string input and does all the requisite work to tokenize it, including normalizing and stubbing.

You should probably avoid the cast for everything but text representations of tsvector.

## Examples

Here we read the string 'test testing tested' as three tsvector lexemes with undefined positions, notice the output lacks stubbing

```
test=# select 'test testing tested'::tsvector;
         tsvector          
---------------------------
 'test' 'tested' 'testing'
(1 row)
```

Here we "convert" a string of words to lexemes with positions by sending the string through the process specified in your specific `TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION`, in my case for `english`.

```
test=# SELECT to_tsvector('test testing tested');
 to_tsvector  
--------------
 'test':1,2,3
(1 row)
```

Here we explicitly tell PostgreSQL to use the `simple` text search configuration.

```
test=# SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'test testing tested');
           to_tsvector           
---------------------------------
 'test':1 'tested':3 'testing':2
(1 row)
```

So what is the cast used for? You could however use it for something like this

```
SELECT $$'test':1 'tested':3 'testing':2$$::tsvector @@ 'testing';
```

Here is another case demonstrating what it does.. (returns true)

```
SELECT to_tsvector(test) = to_tsvector(test)::text::tsvector
FROM ( VALUES
  ( 'This is my test. Hello from testing test tested' )
) AS t(test);
```

If you're getting the tsvector over the wire, or serializing it as text in the case of `pg_dump`, that can be useful.